# Trying to Use an ItemExporter in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to implement some sort of Item Exporter in my code.  My basic code is right now to scrape si.com for batting averages, just as an example.  The results are presented in one long row, and I'd like to modify the output as it's stored in the .csv file to put it in a column instead.  Below I'm including the spider, and the item exporter I'm using is just the basic one found [here.](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters)  What I really want to have happen is take each item and store the results in columns next to each other instead of one long row with all three results consecutively.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import XmlItemExporter

from mlb1.items import MlbItem

class MLBSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "si.com"
   allowed_domains = ["si.com"]
   start_urls = [
       http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/baseball/mlb/stats/2011/batting/ml_0_byBATTING_AVG.html"
       ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="cnnSASD_sport-mlb"]/div[@class="cnnSASD_page-leadersPlayersExpandedStats"]/div[@class="cnnStatsContent"]')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = MlbItem()
           item['name'] = site.select('//table[@class="cnnSASD_first"]/*/td[@class="cnnCol1"]//text()').extract()
           item['team'] = site.select('//table[@class="cnnSASD_first"]/*/td[@class="cnnCol2"]//text()').extract()
           item['batave'] = site.select('//table[@class="cnnSASD_first"]/*/td[@class="cnnColHighlight"]//text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items
```

I'm still very new at Python Coding so the scrapy documentation isn't much help.  When I try running the code, I get an error of, "ImportError: Error loading object 'mlb1.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': cannot import name signals".  Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example for extracting player names

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    player_names = hxs.select('//table[@class="cnnSASD_first"]//td[@class="cnnCol1"]/a')
    for p_name in player_names:
        l = XPathItemLoader(item=MlbItem(), selector=p_name )
        l.add_xpath('name', 'text()')
        yield l.load_item()
```

In scrapy command line, use `--set FEED_URI=items.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv` . This will dump your names to `items.csv` file. No need to write your feed exporter. You can model your xpath for team names on similar lines

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot.  I had done something which was a little bit longer and involved also loading a quick converter that I wrote, but this is a great program, does what I'm looking for as well.  It'll be good to have both at my disposal as different sites will have different formats.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Jeff, you are welcome. As the size of items grows (i.e. in millions), you can consider writing these items to an sqlite db instead of csv. It's also useful in case there's a crash and the csv file is not written