# pumping items out to csv file using python scrapy - issue with how outputted in csv file

Tags: python, scrapy

Having an issue where I want to add output to a csv file but it does not start below the field name it is placed in the next row in sequence as opposed to placing it at row 2 when populating the playerMins item in the csv file. Can someone please tell me where my code is going wrong?? Here it is:

```
class EspnSpider3(BaseSpider):
    name = "espn3.org"
    allowed_domains = ["espn3.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/boxscore?gameId=310502004"

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = EspnItem()
        rows = []
        playerName = []
        playerMins = []

        # player names 
        p_names = hxs.select('(//table[@class="mod-data"][1]/tbody/tr)//a/text()').extract()
        for p_name in p_names:
            print p_name
            yield EspnItem(playerName=p_name)

        # minutes
        p_minutes = hxs.select('(//table[@class="mod-data"][1]/tbody/tr)/td[2]').extract()
        for p_minute in p_minutes:
            print p_minute
            yield EspnItem(playerMins=p_minute)
```

Comment: Where is your code to output to CSV?

Comment: scrapy crawl espn3.org --set FEED_URI=items.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv

Comment: @D P: It's not really clear what problem you're having. Can you reword it?

Comment: Currently, when items are populated in the csv file the first item for field "player name" will populate for the first 23 elements starting from row 2 in the csv file to row 24. Then the next field "player minutes" will start populating elements at row 25 and leave 24 blanks above it in the csv file!! I thought the behaviour would be to start populating at row 2 instead, but it does not. Any ideas????

Comment: help i'm drowning! im a python loving noob :o)

Answer (score 2):

Was able to solve my issue, after much googling and rtfm: [Trying to Use an ItemExporter in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484696/trying-to-use-an-itemexporter-in-scrapy/6489045#6489045)

Here is my working code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    player_names = hxs.select('(//table[@class="mod-data"][1]/tbody/tr)')
    for p_name in player_names:
        l = XPathItemLoader(item=EspnItem(), selector=p_name )
        l.add_xpath('playerName', 'td[1]/a/text()')
        l.add_xpath('playerMins', 'td[2]')
        yield l.load_item()
```